# Grumbling vs Grumble (as nouns)

Tags: word-choice

According to my dictionary, "grumbling" is a complaint about something, but "grumble" is also a complaint about something. I am used to using the "normal nouns - verbs as nouns" not gerund form as a noun. Someone told me that in the following sentences, "grumbling" must be used instead of "grumble", but they can't say why.

> We didn't hear any grumbling about the food.
>
> She paid up with some grumbling.

Again, I would use "grumble" instead.

Comment: *Why* would you use "grumble" in those examples, given that native speakers wouldn't?

Answer (score 2):

A *grumble* would be a single complaint or complaining noise. *Grumbling* would be the gerund form of the verb *grumble* and hence an act of complaining or making complaining noises—allowing it to be used as an uncountable or plural to suggest different complaints.

> We didn't hear any grumbling about the food.
>
> We didn't hear a single grumble about the food.
>
> We didn't hear any grumbles about the food.
>
> We're always hearing grumblings about the food.

All work. Striclty "didn't hear a grumble" is as grammatical as the second, but because *grumble* has diminutive connotations, "a single grumble" works a bit better.